# Sitecore 8.1 Update 3 Error Loading Hook

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore8.1

I'm upgrading my site from 8.1 initil release to sitecore 8.1 update 3 and when trying to open the index manager I have the following error:

```
21396 2016:08:25 11:07:39 ERROR Error loading hook: <hook type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Hooks.Initializer, Sitecore.ContentSearch" patch:source="Sitecore.ContentSearch.config" xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" />
Exception: Sitecore.Exceptions.ConfigurationException
Message: Could not create instance of type: System.String. No matching constructor was found.
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetInnerObject(XmlNode paramNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.AssignProperties(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Object obj, Boolean assert, Boolean deferred, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateFromReference(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetInnerObject(XmlNode paramNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.AssignProperties(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Object obj, Boolean assert, Boolean deferred, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetInnerObject(XmlNode paramNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.AssignProperties(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Object obj, Boolean assert, Boolean deferred, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchManager.get_SearchConfiguration()
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Hooks.Initializer.Initialize()
   at Sitecore.Events.Hooks.HookManager.LoadAll()
```

Any ideas how to solve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a wrong configuration with the file "Sitecore.ListManagement.Lucene.IndexConfiguration.config" in which the following line was in incorrect location

```xml
<field fieldName="segmentation" storageType="YES" indexType="NOT_ANALYZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error, it sounds like there is an issue with the initialization hook.  If you temporarily comment out the`<hook type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Hooks.Initializer, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />` line (usually somewhere around line 64) in /App_Config/Sitecore.ContentSearch.config does the error go away, or do you get a different error?

Comment: When commenting this configuration another related crash will appear